# Why some fields of a object can be automatically initialized sometimes?(C++ in Eclipse using MacOSX GCC)

Tags: c++, arrays, eclipse, object, initialization

My title might be confusing, please read on. ***The question seems long, but rather simple to understand.***

I am using Eclipse Oxygen MacOSX GCC to write C++. In my project, I have a class called FilterArray, and inside of it there are three private fields:

```
int arrayLength;
int * originalArray;
int * filteredArray;
```

And, (1)a function that prints out the array (2)a function to set array length with a random number up to 50 (3)a function to initialize the original array (4)a function that's to filter the original array and store the filtered array in filteredArray, several getter functions, and so on.

```
void FilterArray::printArray(int *arr);
void FilterArray::setArrayLength();
void FilterArray::createOrginalArray(); //random value assigned to each index
void FilterArray::filterTheArray(); //by a certain algorithm
void FilterArray::getOriginalArray();
```

I made three test cases to test my filterArray() function in main(). At first, I forgot to initialize the fliteredArray with the size(only declared it) for each of the objects, but to my surprise, two of the original arrays gets filtered succesfully, and the program gets halted at the process when the function filtered the third array.

I soon realized that the problem is indeed that I forgot to initialize the filtered array with the size so when the function runs, fliteredArray[index] would make no sense, however, why this situation did happen to the first two objects, but not the third??

**If you need to further understand my question, please refer to the following code. I've cut it to the most succinct.**

In my FilterArray.hpp:

```
#ifndef FILTERARRAY_HPP_
#define FILTERARRAY_HPP_

class FilterArray {

    int *originalArray;
    int arrayLength;
    int *filteredArray;

public:

    // Constructor
    FilterArray();

    void setArraySize();
    int getArraySize();
    int * getOriginalArray(int index);
    int * getFilteredArray();

    void printArray(int *arr);

};



#endif /* FILTERARRAY_HPP_ */
```

In my FilterArray.cpp:

```
#include "FilterArray.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#include <math.h>

// Constructor
FilterArray::FilterArray(){
}

// function definitions

void FilterArray::setArraySize(){
    this->arrayLength = rand() % 25 + 25;
}

int FilterArray::getArraySize(){
    return this->arrayLength;
}

int * FilterArray::getOriginalArray(int index){
    return &this->originalArray[index];
}

int * FilterArray::getFilteredArray(){
    return this->filteredArray;
}

void FilterArray::printArr(int *arr){
    cout <<"["<<arr[0]<<", ";
    for (int i = 1; i < this->arrayLength - 1; i++){
        cout <<arr[i]<<", ";
    }
    cout <<arr[this->arrayLength - 1]<<"]"<<endl;
}
```

In my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

#include "FilterArray.hpp"

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    // Test Cases
    // Object array1 is for case 1, and the same for 2 and 3.
    FilterArray *array1 = new FilterArray();
    FilterArray *array2 = new FilterArray();
    FilterArray *array3 = new FilterArray();
    array1->setArraySize();
    array2->setArraySize();
    array3->setArraySize();
    cout <<"1"<<endl;
    //array1->printArr(array1->getOriginalArray(0));
    array1->printArr(array1->getFilteredArray());
    cout <<"2"<<endl;
    //array2->printArr(array2->getOriginalArray(0));
    array2->printArr(array2->getFilteredArray());
    cout <<"3"<<endl;
    //array3->printArr(array3->getOriginalArray(0));
    array3->printArr(array3->getFilteredArray());

    delete array1;
    array1 = NULL;
    delete array2;
    array2 = NULL;
    delete array3;
    array3 = NULL;

    return 1;
}
```

And to my suprise, the output is:

```
1
[8, 0, 0, 0, -824775304, 32767, -666960016, 32767, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 1, -1201811687, 32767, -824775248, 32767, -824816597, 32767, 17, 40, 40, 0, 0, 0, -824775295, 32767, -666959792]
2
[524288, 0, 0, 0, -310902784, 2147471062, -9437184, 2147473470, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1769472, 65536, -820445184, 2147465309, -307232768, 2147471062, 1277886464, 2147471062, 1114112, 2621440, 2621440, 0, 0, 0, -310312960, 2147471062, 5242880, 2147473471, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1769472, 196608]
3
```

You can see in my main() there is nowhere I initialized the filteredArray, but why the first two objects can have it, but not the third? I delete the pointer after the main though, or is it because the program halts before the deletion of the pointer or what?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: As the old saying goes, undefined behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @molbdnilo yea molbdnilo, I think you the one also answered my last question. Thanks again, I guess that's the reason too lol!